# Return child or parent after a regex find javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, dom

Hopefully this is a quick question that can be answered.  Is it possible after running a regexp and it turn true to return the parent(s) of the dom element where it was found?

Any sample code would be greatly appreciated.

So basic layout I hope.

A variable for the expression

an if statement to check if the value of text exists

another if statement if it returns true and have it change the variable x value in the table based on the location of where the text was found " document.getElementsByTagName("table:)[x]. "

For example if there where three tables in the html document but only one table contained the word "cat" is it possible to return the id in the dom tree for that TagName and where the regexp exists

Something like this like this:

```
mybody      = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
mytable     = mybody.getElementsByTagName("table")[Variable Based On Where the text        is];
```

I am hoping it is just as simple as the regexp turning true and allowing me to return the  parent id on a true event at set the variable above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use XPath, this would be the answer:

```
var iterator = document.evaluate(
    '//table[contains(descendant-or-self::text(), "string to search")]', 
    document.body
);

while ((node = iterator.iterateNext()) !== null) {
  // this should be a <table> element
}
```